# Ререндеринг компонентов NEXT js

Tags: reactjs, react-hook, nextjs, render

Есть функция PreviewImage, которая выполняет загрузку фотографий с input,
также используется drag and drop для сортировки по индексу, при перетаскивании элементов по индексу, все картинки на сайте начинают мигать, тем сам просиходит их ререндеринг, useCallback() не справляется. Что делать или как можно изменить?

```
    const PreviewImage = useCallback(() => {
    const removeItemGallery = (index) => {
        let temp = uploadedFiles.filter((item, idx) => idx !== index)
        if (temp.length < 10) setFileLimit(false)
        setUploadedFiles(temp)
    }

    const handlerDragStart = (e, index) => {
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move'
        e.target.style.opacity = 0.5
        setIndexDraggedItem(index)
        setDraggedItem(uploadedFiles[index])
    }

    const handlerDragEnd = (e, index) => {
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move'
        e.target.style.opacity = 1
        setIndexDraggedItem(null)
        setDraggedItem(null)
    }

    const handlerDragOver = (e, file, index) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (index === indexDraggedItem) return;
        let position = index
        if (e.nativeEvent.offsetX >= (e.target.offsetWidth / 2)) {
            position = index + 1
        }
        let temp = [...uploadedFiles.filter((item) => item.sort !== draggedItem.sort)]
        temp.splice(position, 0, draggedItem)
        temp.map((item, idx) => {
            item['sort'] = idx
        })
        setUploadedFiles(temp)
        console.log(position);
        // console.log(e.target.offsetWidth);
    }

    useEffect(() => {

    }, [])

    return uploadedFiles.length > 0 ?
        uploadedFiles.map((file, index) =>
            <div
                key={index}
                className='relative'
                draggable={true}
                onDragStart={e => handlerDragStart(e, index)}
                onDragEnd={e => handlerDragEnd(e, index)}
                onDragOver={e => handlerDragOver(e, file, index)}
            >
                <img src={URL.createObjectURL(file)} className='h-16 w-16 object-cover object-center rounded-md' />
                <button
                    type='button'
                    className='absolute -right-3 -top-3 rounded-md'
                    onClick={() => removeItemGallery(index)}
                >
                    <XMarkIcon className='h-6 w-6 text-red-500 hover:text-red-600' />
                </button>
            </div>)
        : <span> Добавьте фото </span>
}, [uploadedFiles, draggedItem, indexDraggedItem])
```

Comment: Почитайте, что такое key и для чего оно надо. Если коротко, то нельзя применять в вашем случае индекс, стоит прокинуть какой нибудь id. И useCallback в данном случае ничего не делает, про него тоже стоит прочитать подробнее и почему он работает в связке с memo.